# Differential module

Tags: modules, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

Given a descending semi-exact sequence $C$ of $R-$modules

$$ C:   \cdot \cdot \cdot \to C_{n+1} \to   C_{n} \to C_{n-1} \to  \cdot \cdot \cdot    $$, consider the direct sum $$  X= \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} C_n $$ and the restriction $ d: X \to X $ of the cartesian product of all edge operators $ \partial_n: C_{n} \to C_{n-1} $. I need to prove that $ d \circ d=0$ and $H(X)= \displaystyle \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} H_n(C)$. Where $H(X)= Ker(d) / Im(d)$  and  $H_n (C)= Ker ( \partial_{n}) / Im (\partial_{n+1})$

Comment: You need to show that the kernel of $\partial$ is the sum of the kernels of $\partial_n$'s, and the same for the images. These are rather straightforward. The tricky part is to show that the quotient and sum commute, but there you can use the morphism $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\ker(\partial_n)\to\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}H_n(C)$, given by $\sum x_n\mapsto \sum x_n+\text{im}(\partial_{n+1})$, the kernel of which is the sum of the images.

Comment: Correction, you used $d$, not $\partial$.

Comment: I don't know how to define $ d: X  \to X $  to prove that $ d \circ d =0$

Comment: Okay, so if $x\in X$, then $x=\sum x_n$, and so $d(x)=\sum\partial_n(x_n)$. It follows immediately that $d\circ d=(\sum \partial_n)\circ(\sum\partial_m) = \sum (\partial_n\circ\partial_{n+1})$ (the domains and codomains must match!), and so the composite is zero. Actually, always when you are defining a morphism as a sum of morphisms, the result is like that.

Comment: Thanks. I think that I understood

Comment: Nice to be able to help. :)